# In SQL, convert numbers to the next available number in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a list of numbers that are ages.

I want to have SQL select statement that converts the ages to the specified sequence. The user chooses the starting / ending value and the interval.

Let's say they select a sequence that starts from 3 and intervals at 2, up to 100.

The SQL code I would manually input would be:

```
SELECT
AGE,
IIF(AGE < 3, 3, IIF(AGE < 3+2, 3+2, IIF(AGE < 3+4, 3+4, 
  IIF(AGE < 3+6, 3+6, ..., 100)))) as AGE_ADJ
FROM
MY_TABLE
```

The result would be ADJ_AGE column like:

| AGE | ADJ_AGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 9 |

Is there a more clever way to do this? With so many ages the nested IF is too long to type out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT AGE,
       CASE 
         WHEN AGE <= :start THEN :start
         ELSE :start + :interval + (AGE - :start - 1) / :interval * :interval
       END ADJ_AGE  
FROM tablename
```

Replace `:start` and `:interval` with the values that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36eb4a269327c2b861ffa5375bb75027).

Comment: I think there needs to be rounding, this simple variation works: `CASE    WHEN AGE <= :start THEN :start​  ELSE  :start + :interval  *  CEILING((AGE - :start) / :interval))
END ADJ_AGE`. If you agree, can you edit your answer and then I'll accept

Comment: @FG120 I assume that AGE's data type is INTEGER. SQL Server does integer division between integers so there is no need to round. Check the demo in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the value ranges using `values()` and then use `join`:

```
select t.*, v.enda
from t left join
     (values (1, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)) v(starta, enda)
     on t.age >= v.starta and t.age <= v.enda;
```